# Displaying super- and subscript

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm currently working on an UWP app which also deals with math. Therefore i parse formulae and display them as `inlines` in a `RichTextBlock`. As you can imagine, I also want to display sub- and superscription - but I haven't yet found a way to do so. I know, there is something called `BaselineAlignment` in WPF, but it seems that this is not supported in UWP.
I'm currently also about to figure out how to best display fraction lines and roots. I've thought about building my own control for this purpose, but if somebody knows a better approach it would be nice to know.
I'm gladful for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply subscript and superscript to text in `RichTextBlock`, we can take advantage of [Typography.Variants attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.typography.variants.aspx). For example:

```
<RichTextBlock FontSize="36">
    <Paragraph FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
        2<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">3</Run>
        14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">th</Run>
    </Paragraph>

    <Paragraph FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
        H<Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">2</Run>O
        Footnote<Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">4</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

And the output would like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `WebBrowser` control, and just locally include one of many javascript libraries for rendering LaTex.

Comment: Thought about that earlier, but given that there isn't only one formula to be shown - but, depending on type of input, quite a lot - loading a WebView for each of them doesn't seem to be the most performant way...