# UWP Win 10 XAML Super/Sub script rendering issues

Tags: uwp, richtextbox, subscript, superscript

I'm working on UWP app that has lots of text rendering, including some formulas and math equations. It's all fun and games until you bump into Superscript or Subscript parts of text with Cyrillic letters.
I've tried a lot of different font families:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Palatino 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Linotype 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Calibri">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Calibri 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Calibri 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Arial 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Arial 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Segoe 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="UI 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Segoe 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="WP 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe Script">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Segoe 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Script 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Sitka">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Superscript Sitka 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Subscript Sitka 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Verdana">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Super Verdana 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Subs Verdana 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="суп1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Trebuchet 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="MS 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="9" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial Nova">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Arial 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Arial 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Consolas">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Consolas 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Consolas 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Courier New">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Courier 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="New 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="12" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Gill Sans Nova">
            <Run>Normal Text</Run>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Gill  123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Sans Nova 123"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="супер1"/>
            <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="саб2"/>
        </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

and received this as a result:
[image: Render of given text]

As you can see, some fonts will not render sub/super script at all, some will do but only for Latin letters and/or digits, and none will work with Cyrillic.
Is there any way to force UWP app render those symbols correctly?

---

P.S.
I've seen questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950827/superscript-or-subscript-in-textblock) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120025/displaying-super-and-subscript), and none of answers worked for me.

P.P.S. I've also seen some mentions of `BaselineAlignment` property, but it's not available in UWP.

Comment: Some fonts do not support superscript or subscript,and we have no way to force UWP app render those symbols correctly.You could contact the font vendor to report the fonts which do not support superscript and subscript and let them update the fonts.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT so, I should contact Microsoft, as I'm using default Win 10 fonts, right?

Comment: It's better to contact the font vendor,because the Microsoft is not necessarily the supplier.You can see the supplier information in the font details in the Settings.